# Method called twice instead of single time

Tags: vba, lisp, autocad

I have trouble with calling methods from lisp command in Autocad. I am using lisp file  in Autocad. When I call the macro name from Autocad it calls the method twice instead of single time.

In My lisp file

```
(defun c:Export_N()
(setvar "cmdecho" 0)
(command "-vbarun" "Export_New")
(princ)
)
```

In calling lisp file form Autocad:

```
openMacro = "Export_N " & vbCr
Set newButton = NewToolbar.AddToolbarButton("", "Export", "Export", openMacro)

SmallBitmapName = AppPath & "\" & "Tool Icon\MReport.bmp"     
LargeBitmapName = AppPath & "\" & "Tool Icon\MReport.bmp"     
newButton.SetBitmaps SmallBitmapName, LargeBitmapName
```

Comment: Can you provide the code ?

Comment: In my lisp file:  (defun c:Export_N()
(setvar "cmdecho" 0)
(command "-vbarun" "Export_New")
(princ)
)

Answer (score 3):

Your macro includes a space and a carriage return. The space enters the command, and the carriage return repeats the command. Remove one or the other to prevent the command from repeating.